# Anyone could demo some code about layout UITableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview, dynamically-generated

Each `UITableViewCell` contains several labels and images (just like the home page for a twitter App below). How should I layout the labels and images, resizing `UITableViewCell`, dynamically?

1. Data is taken from the back-end, if it has no image then `UITableViewCell` will adapt that.
2. `UITableView`, like list view in android,  I have already finished.

[image: Twitter App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at a tutorial about custom tableview cells.

Checkout this one http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ for example.

Comment: i got answer myself: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html
and demo is here http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html. thnx NikosM